# Garbage value as output on using gcc on M1 Macbook

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

This is the code that is being written and executed and i am using gcc compiler for the same.
I am using VSCode for Apple Silicon on M1 MacBook Air.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Function to calculate the parity bits
void calculateParityBits(int data[], int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    // Calculate the parity bits for each position that is a power of 2
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int p = 1 << i;
        int count = 0;
        for (j = p - 1; j < n; j += 2*p) {
            for (k = 0; k < p && (j + k) < n; k++) {
                if (data[j + k] == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Set the parity bit to 1 if the count of 1s is odd
        if (count % 2 != 0) {
            data[p - 1] = 1;
        }
    }
}

// Function to print the Hamming code
void printHammingCode(int data[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d", data[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Input the data
    int data[100];
    int n, m;
    printf("Enter the length of the data: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the number of parity bits: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter the data bits: ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);
    }
    // Calculate the parity bits
    calculateParityBits(data, n, m);
    // Print the Hamming code
    printf("Hamming code: ");
    printHammingCode(data, n + m);
    return 0;
}
```

The output on the terminal is as follows:

```
Enter the length of the data: 4  
Enter the number of parity bits: 3
Enter the data bits: 1
0
1
0
Hamming code: 1110-10634524905380585521837314128%
```

The output returns garbage values. This code is working on online compilers.
Please suggest appropriate fixes

I have tried resolving by using other methods to execute it but to no avail.

Comment: What output are you expecting?  And have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: It might help you to output a space between each value: I get `Hamming code: 1 1 1 0 4194304 0 10`.

Comment: In `calculateParityBits()`, you sometimes set elements of `data` to 1, but you never set any to 0.  You need to cover both alternatives.  Also, when you do set a bit, it is `data[p - 1]`, which index looks wrong.  Maybe you want something more like `data[n + i] = count % 2;` (unconditionally).

Comment: I was checking this: you have never written to elements 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: on the point of using a debugger: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/11107541